# File transfer from Kotlin Android App to the server using SFTP protocol

Tags: android, kotlin, sftp

I've been using the ftp4j library in kotlin to transfer files via old FTP protocol.

Now I have to deal with transferring files via the SFTP protocol. Are there exist any kotlin libraries that can I use? What dependencies should I use in Android Studio and how I can simple connect with FTP server throught SFTP protocol to upload, download or list the files on server.

Answer (score 0):

I use JCraft JSch library that is a Java implementtion of SSH2.

kotlin gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.55"
}
```

kotlin function:

```
val REMOTE_HOST = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
val USERNAME = "xxxx"
val PASSWORD = "xxxx"
val REMOTE_PORT = 22

fun copyFileToSftp(srcFile: File, ftpPath: String): Boolean {

    var jschSession: Session? = null

    try {
        val jsch = JSch()
        jsch.setKnownHosts("/home/mkyong/.ssh/known_hosts")
        jschSession = jsch.getSession(USERNAME, REMOTE_HOST, REMOTE_PORT)
        jschSession.setPassword(PASSWORD)

        val config = Properties()
        config["StrictHostKeyChecking"] = "no"
        jschSession.setConfig(config)

        jschSession.connect(10000)
        val sftp: Channel = jschSession.openChannel("sftp")

        sftp.connect(5000)
        val channelSftp: ChannelSftp = sftp as ChannelSftp

        channelSftp.put(srcFile.absolutePath, ftpPath)
        channelSftp.exit()

    } catch (e: JSchException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        return false
    } catch (e: SftpException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        return false
    } finally {
        jschSession?.disconnect()
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Do not use `StrictHostKeyChecking=no`. And mainly do not suggest it to others, without explaining the security consequences!